# TypeError raised while trying to use range

Tags: python, python-2.7

While i'm running the following code it shows a `TypeError`:

```
a = int(input("Enter the iteration value:"))

b=[]

for c in range[0,a]:
    d=int(input("Enter:"))
    b.append(d)

f=0    
for e in b:
    f = f + e

print f
```

It shows the following error

```
Enter the iteration value:5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/app/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.5.0.201405201709/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1845, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/var/app/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.5.0.201405201709/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1373, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/opt/odoo/v7.0_cust_mod/Python/print.py", line 68, in <module>
    for c in range[0,a]:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for the `range()` function:

```
for c in range[0,a]:
```

Note the square brackets, you should use parentheses instead:

```
for c in range(0, a):
```

The square brackets are used for *subscriptions*, which means Python will try and use a `__getitem__` method on the `range` function object. There is no such method, which is why you get your traceback.